# How to fill a polygon with an arbitrarily fine triangular mesh in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a football (aka soccer ball) in Three.js. I have the geometry for a truncated isocahedron - the set of vertices and hexagonal and pentagonal faces that make up the underlying polyhedron. Now I need to project these onto the sphere. I will do this by:

(1) filling each polygon with a (sufficiently fine) triangular mesh then 
(2) scale each vertex distance from the origin to be the radius of the sphere.

I'm going to draw distinct textures on each polygon so I need to retain their identity and know the UVs.

Can anyone recommend a JavaScript library to do (1)? It's not difficult mathematically but very laborious in code.

Thanks.

Comment: The word you're looking for is [tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation_(computer_graphics)), and the helper you're (potentially) looking for is the [TesselationModifier](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_tessellation.html).

Comment: `THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry( radius, detail )` may help get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I looked at TesselateModifier (it's not TessellationModifier) which is the right kind of library. However I notice in the example https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_tessellation.html it gets applied 6 times to the geometry without explanation. In my case, applying it fewer times leads to obvious holes in the geometry; even 6 times isn't quite enough. BTW, I'm generating a *truncated* icosahedron, not an icosahedron, so IcosahedronBufferGeometry won't do.